# How much more likely to die of covid, once infected, are you if you have no access to medical treatment?

Tags: covid-19, covid-19-datasets, oxygen, mortality-rate

How much more likely to die of covid, given that you are already infected with it, are you when you have no access to medical treatment compared to when you have access to full medical treatment including pure oxygen and intubation as needed ? I couldn't find any information about this anywhere. Feel free to assume an age of 60 years and no comorbidities (i.e. perfect health apart from being infected with covid).

https://www.forbes.com/sites/theapothecary/2020/10/06/what-is-your-risk-of-dying-from-covid-19/?sh=116da1e61592 is very much more to my taste than most articles about covid, as far as it goes, but it makes no mention of what effect on your chances of dying the lack of medical treatment has nor about a hypothetical lack of pure oxygen and/or intubation equipment in the hospital where you would be treated if you got seriously ill from the covid that you are infected with.

Comment: By "more likely to die of COVID" do you mean "if you get COVID, how much more likely are you to die than if you did not get COVID"?  Obviously you are infinitely more likely to die of COVID if you get it, since you can't die of it if you don't get it.

Comment: @BrenBarn No, that isn't what I mean. I have edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: If you're ill enough to need intubation but you're in a country where medical care isn't available to you, I'd say the odds of your survival are quite low. But how would we obtain reliable data on that? It seems unlikely people would be available to track and record deaths when resources are stretched so thin that the medical system has broken down.

Comment: @CareyGregory If a hospital is running low on oxygen, doctors might have to decide who gets oxygen and who doesn't, or it might decided some other way, perhaps by an insurance company. Or perhaps some hospitals have plenty and others none,  and/or one or more hospitals would have oxygen for everyone that 'needs' it, and other times none for anyone. In any case, doctors would over time perhaps notice the difference in survival rate when there is oxygen available and when there isn't. Also maybe some patients refuse oxygen, on religious or other grounds, and doctors will learn from that.

Comment: You've changed your question. You asked about "no access to medical treatment," not just a lack of one item such as oxygen. My point was that if the medical system is so overwhelmed that it's turning away patients, it's unlikely anyone is keeping track of those patients so the question probably can't be answered.

Comment: @CareyGregory 'You asked about "no access to medical treatment," not just a lack of one item such as oxygen.' Good point. I guess I conflated absence of piped oxygen with absence of medical care. That was wrong of me. I forgot about the drugs and so on that can also be used with some success. Perhaps I overestimated the importance of oxygen in my comment (though not in the question where I didn't actually ask about oxygen but only mentioned it in passing). I guessed (without much justification) that absence of piped oxygen would be equivalent to absence of medical treatment.

Comment: @CareyGregory You may well be right that an overwhelmed medical system is unlikely to keep track of the patients they turn away. On the other hand it's not impossible that *someone* did follow up on a representative sample of some group of patients that were turned away. And there are other reasons that a patient might get no treatment. Perhaps in some country somewhere some subset of prisoners in a POW camp have access while others don't, or maybe some ethnic group, or economic group.